# How to write query for this situation to get the max date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have issues in query:

```
 priceDeatil 
 ProductCode  BusinessUnit  price   DateFrom     DateTo
  10001         ORB          12.00   12-08-2011   31-09-2015
  10001         ORB          21.00   01.08-2011   15-11-2011
  10002         ORB          31.00   01.04-2011   15-08-2012
  10003         ORB          42.00   01.05-2011   15-08-2012
```

My query is:

```
 SELECT     BusinessUnit, ProductCode,  DateFrom, DateTo, Price
 FROM         WMPriceDetail
 WHERE     (DateFrom < 'Sep 01 2011') AND (DateTo > 'Sep 01 2011' OR DateTo = '')
 ORDER BY ProductCode
```

This return

```
   priceDeatil 
 ProductCode  BusinessUnit  price   DateFrom     DateTo
  10001         ORB          12.00   12-08-2011   31-09-2015
  10001         ORB          21.00   01.08-2011   15-11-2011
  10002         ORB          31.00   01.04-2011   15-08-2012
  10003         ORB          42.00   01.05-2011   15-08-2012
```

But Here `productCode 10001` return two records; That time I want to get the Max Date i.e `12-08-2011` .

So desired result should be like this:

```
   priceDeatil 
 ProductCode  BusinessUnit  price   DateFrom     DateTo
  10001         ORB          12.00   12-08-2011   31-09-2015
  10002         ORB          31.00   01.04-2011   15-08-2012
  10003         ORB          42.00   01.05-2011   15-08-2012
```

How to write query for this situation?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  And why did you tag this as mysqli?

Comment: Just a heads up I hope that is not real data because there are only 30 days in September 2015 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT     BusinessUnit, ProductCode,  DateFrom, DateTo, Price FROM
 (SELECT    BusinessUnit, ProductCode,  DateFrom, DateTo, Price, 
 rank() over (PARTITION BY ProductCode ORDER BY DateFrom DESC) rank_num
 FROM  WMPriceDetail
 WHERE (DateFrom < 'Sep 01 2011') AND (DateTo > 'Sep 01 2011' OR DateTo = '') t 
 WHERE rank_num=1
 ORDER BY ProductCode
```

Comment: You should have the ORDER BY ProductCode after the WHERE rank_num=1 because you cannot have order by conditions in subqueries.

Comment: Hi This query is not working.There are two `WHERE clause` Please can you help me?

Comment: The first `WHERE` clause is for the sub query and the second `WHERE` clause is for the outer query. So that is syntactically valid. Are you getting an error (or) is it not returning results?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
select BusinessUnit, ProductCode,  DateFrom, DateTo, Price from WMPriceDetail 
where DateFrom  in (select MAX(datefrom) from WMPriceDetail group by ProductCode)
```